# "Plugin "react" was conflicted between Error" on Linode Nginx server after "npm build"

Tags: reactjs, nginx, eslint

When I try to build by website files using 'npm build' I get the error that it failed to compile and then:

[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "src/package.json » eslint-config-react-app » /home/aden/IPWebsite/my-app/src/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js" and "BaseConfig » /home/aden/IPWebsite/my-app/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.